# capsh works but systemd doesn't - Openvpn unprivileged user

Tags: bash, debian, systemd, openvpn, capabilities

**OS: Debian 11

Package: OpenVPN 2.5.1**

**Background:**

> After an update, Openvpn-2.5 clients can no longer use **iproute** to
> modify the interface and configure routes pushed by the OpenVPN server
> after root privileges are dropped and the system unit running as an
> unprivileged user. Based on discussions in these two threads on the
> iproute issue:
> https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/68480
> https://phabricator.vyos.net/T3805
>
> A workaround was suggested to remove user & group directives from
> `/etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf` and to add Ambient Capabilities,
> `User=tunnel`, `Group=tunnel` to a separate .service file.

There is already an existing Openvpn service file (openvpn@openvpn.service) in `/lib/systemd/system` so we created a new directory and included a .service file in it - `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@openvpn.service.d/override.conf`

```
# separate service file containing User and group directives along with Ambient capabilities

[Service]

User=tunnel
Group=tunnel
SecureBits=keep-caps

ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sudo --non-interactive /usr/sbin/openvpn --rmtun --dev tun0
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sudo --non-interactive /usr/sbin/openvpn --mktun --dev tun0 --dev-type tun --user tunnel --group tunnel
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/sudo --non-interactive /usr/sbin/openvpn --rmtun --dev tun0

AmbientCapabilities=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
```

Ran the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo chown -R tunnel:tunnel /etc/openvpn /run/openvpn
sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --rmtun --dev tun0
sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --mktun --dev tun0 --dev-type tun --user tunnel --group tunnel
cd /etc/openvpn/
sudo -u tunnel openvpn /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf
```

**Error**

The expectation was that the unprivileged `User=tunnel` will have the ambient capabilities to open up tun0 and modify the interface to complete the openvpn connection. However, it encountered an error.

```
#Error after running sudo -u tunnel openvpn /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf

2022-06-24 17:32:08 us=174691 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
2022-06-24 17:32:08 us=174755 do_ifconfig, ipv4=1, ipv6=0
2022-06-24 17:32:08 us=174844 net_iface_mtu_set: mtu 1500 for tun0
2022-06-24 17:32:08 us=175005 sitnl_send: rtnl: generic error (-1): Operation not permitted
2022-06-24 17:32:08 us=175084 Linux can't set mtu (1500) on tun0
2022-06-24 17:32:08 us=175142 Exiting due to fatal error
```

**The solution that works**

However, with capsh, I gave Ambient Capability directly to the Openvpn executable with `user=tunnel` privileges, and nothing in the systemd service:

```
sudo /sbin/capsh --keep=1 --user='tunnel' --inh='cap_ipc_lock,cap_net_admin,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_sys_chroot,cap_dac_override,cap_audit_write' --addamb='cap_ipc_lock,cap_net_admin,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_sys_chroot,cap_dac_override,cap_audit_write' -- -c 'openvpn /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf'
```

**The issue:**

> Why wasn't systemd able to set the Ambient Capabilities for
> user=tunnel whereas capsh was able to? How to make this work with
> systemd?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `sudo -u tunnel` clears ambient capabilities. To confirm, you might try inserting these lines before the last one:

```
/sbin/capsh --print
sudo -u tunnel /sbin/capsh --print
sudo -u tunnel openvpn /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf
```

Comment: sudo -u tunnel /sbin/capsh --print gives Ambient set =
I think you may be correct, tunnel loses its Ambient Capabilities.